# How to set a default value with Html.TextBoxFor (C#) so it is W3C markup compliant?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.textboxfor

I am setting a default value with the following code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @Value = "0"})
```

The problem is the generated code contains two value attributes, breaking W3C markup validation.

```
<input Value="0" data-val="true" data-val-required="Age is required." id="Age" name="Age" type="text" value="" />
```

Notice the capital 'V' and the lowercase 'v' value attributes...

Does anyone know of a work around for the html helper TextBoxFor to only have one value attribute??

Comment: On a side note: you only use the `@` symbol when you need to use a reserved keyword like in `@class`.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the "new { @Value = "0"}" and just use the following...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
```

The value of the input will be whatever value the Age property of the model is.  If you want the default value to be 0, than set the age property of the model to 0.

Answer (score 1):

This happen because the `Value` is not the the same attribute the `value`, HTML 5 is case sensitive and the `Html.TextBoxFor` give the output rightly (considering `value` is the right and `Value` a custom).

Try:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @value = "0"})
```